# How does objectTranslation files work for renaming standard fields

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, tab

We are working with salesforce dx. When I try to relabel a standard field in Salesforce and retrieve that change into dx, the change goes to objectTranslation files. However, by looking at the file names I am a bit confused.

Usually the file and field names is something like [fieldname]-[objectname], like description-case. But there are many fields which don't work in this way. For example, origin is case-origin instead of origin-case, comments is internal-comments-case, and parentId has two files - parent-case and parent-case-id. Why the fields are named in this way and how do they work?